# I copied a project folder to a testing location. Now xcode is editing the original?

Tags: xcode

I would like to test out AutoLayout for my project which already works quite well. I copied the folder in Finder to another location called 'Sandbox'. I start Xcode and edit the 'Sandbox' project. I find that I am editing some of the original files, not the ones in the 'Sandbox'.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry Just checked again It's not true. UBD (User Brain Damage)